# Menu does not show shortcuts

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, typo3, neoscms, typoscript2

I am trying to render a menu in TYPO3 Neos. The Menu works fine, but does not show shortcuts. What do I do wrong?

```
       <f:for each="{items}" as="item" iteration="menuItemIterator">
                    <li class="{item.state}">

                        <f:if condition="{item.subItems}">
                            <f:then>
                                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">{item.label}<b class="caret"></b></a>
                                <f:render section="subList" arguments="{items: item.subItems}"/>
                            </f:then>
                            <f:else>
                                <neos:link.node node="{item.node}">{item.label}</neos:link.node>
                            </f:else>



                        </f:if>
                    </li>
                </f:for>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you also change something in TypoScript? Shortcuts should be rendered in the menu unless they are set to hidden in Menu or the shortcut target is not accessible. So one of those probably applies.